# How to just output value in context.write(k,v)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, output

In my mapreduce job, I just want to output some lines.

But if I code like this:
    context.write(data, null);

the program will throw java.lang.NullPointerException.

I don't want to code like below:
    context.write(data, new Text(""));

because I have to trim the blank space in every line in the output files.

Is there any good ways to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

---

Sorry, it's my mistake. I checked the program carefully, found the reason is I set the Reducer as combiner.

If I do not use the combiner, the statement 
    context.write(data, null); 
in reducer works fine. In the output data file, there is just the data line.

---

Share the NullWritable explanation from hadoop definitive guide:

NullWritable is a special type of Writable, as it has a zero-length serialization. No bytes
are written to, or read from, the stream. It is used as a placeholder; for example, in
MapReduce, a key or a value can be declared as a NullWritable when you don’t need
to use that position—it effectively stores a constant empty value. NullWritable can also
be useful as a key in SequenceFile when you want to store a list of values, as opposed
to key-value pairs. It is an immutable singleton: the instance can be retrieved by calling
NullWritable.get().

Comment: You don't need to trim if you use new Text(""). You have to trim if you use new Text(" ") only. Besides the API also has a Text() default constructor.

Comment: thanks, I have a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [NullWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/NullWritable.html) for this purpose.

Comment: thank you. I have checked the NullWritable class, it suits for me.